# В цикле увеличивать дату +1 месяц

Tags: javascript, datetime

Нужно в таблице увеличивать дату в каждой строке на 1 месяц начиная с текущей даты + 9 мес. Вот так:

```
Июль 2022
Август 2022
Сентябрь 2022
Октябрь 2022
Ноябрь 2022
Декабрь 2022
Январь 2023
Февраль 2023
Март 2023
Апрель 2023
Май 2023
Июнь 2023
Июль 2023
Август 2023
Сентябрь 2023
Октябрь 2023
Ноябрь 2023
Декабрь 2023
Январь 2024
Февраль 2024
Март 2024
Апрель 2024
Май 2024
Июнь 2024
Июль 2024
Август 2024
Сентябрь 2024
```

До конца года пишет правильно, а потом с каждым месяцем увеличивает год.
Так:

```
июль 2022 г.
август 2022 г.
сентябрь 2022 г.
октябрь 2022 г.
ноябрь 2022 г.
декабрь 2022 г.
январь 2023 г.
февраль 2024 г.
март 2025 г.
апрель 2026 г.
май 2027 г.
июнь 2028 г.
июль 2029 г.
август 2030 г.
сентябрь 2031 г.
октябрь 2032 г.
ноябрь 2033 г.
декабрь 2034 г.
январь 2036 г.
февраль 2038 г.
март 2040 г.
апрель 2042 г.
май 2044 г.
июнь 2046 г.
```

Как победить? Полный код страницы:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      var date = new Date(Date.now());
      var StartDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 9)); // начальное значение от текущей даты +9 месяцев = июль 22 г.
      var MonthOfStartDate = StartDate.getMonth();
      for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        date = new Date(StartDate.setMonth(MonthOfStartDate + i)) /* приводим к читабельному виду на русском*/ .toLocaleString('ru', {
          year: 'numeric',
          month: 'long'
        });
        let row = myTable.insertRow(); // добавляем строки в таблицу
        let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = date; // пишем значение
      }
    }
  </script>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      var date = new Date(Date.now());
      var StartDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 9)); // начальное значение от текущей даты +9 месяцев = июль 22 г.
      var MonthOfStartDate = StartDate.getMonth();
      for (i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        date = new Date(StartDate.setMonth(StartDate.getMonth() + 1))
        /* приводим к читабельному виду на русском*/ .toLocaleString('ru', {
          year: 'numeric',
          month: 'long'
        });
        let row = myTable.insertRow(); // добавляем строки в таблицу
        let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = date; // пишем значение
      }
    }
  </script>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```